# Как получить все экземпляры приложения

Tags: c#, .net

Гугление не помогло. Интересует, возможно ли из c# получить созданные экземпляры в текущем приложении. Вообще, именно все прям не нужно, интересуют экземпляры отдельных пользовательских типов.

Костылями неохота делать, можно было бы самому контролировать через статик список загруженные экземпляры, но в либе сложная иерархия и в каждый тип добавлять эти статические списки не хочется совсем.

Comment: Нет, невозможно. </thread>

Comment: Разве что через отладочное API, с замедлением программы во много раз.

Comment: @VladD, а мы не можем действовать примерно как GC? Начать с каких-то корневых элементов и просмотреть все ссылки?

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Непонятно, как это сделать корректно без остановки всех потоков. И как получить без Debug API все корневые элементы (влючая те, которые в стеке).